# Partial derivatives chain rule (calculus II)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was doing some exercises and I came upon this one. I have been thinking about for quite some time, but I'm still not sure about the answer. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

[image: Problem Link]

This is what I have tried:

[image: Attempted Solution]

Is this correct?

Comment: What have you tried Mr. Creeper?

Comment: Hey, I just uploaded what I have tried so far

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you type out the question and your solution using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've voted to reopen your question, because you're a new user, but next time use MathJax as you were instructed to on the ask-a-question page.

Comment: A reference for MathJax for what it's worth - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2x \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+2y \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}.$$
(Similarly for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.)

This results in $$2(x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=0.$$

So, the transformed differential equation is $$\frac{\partial \, z(u,v)}{\partial u}=0.$$

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But I do not know for certain if its the right approach. Its that correct?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer and included one more step. What can you conclude?

Comment: Yes I reached that same conclusion, so I guess its correct right?

Comment: You still have to get rid of the $x$ and $y$ :) I have edited the post and included the answer. Can you explain why we can leave out the $2(x^2-y^2)$?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you did. But why exactly do I have to get rid of x and y?

Comment: Because you want to transform the differential equation from $x, y$ to $u, v$. So at the end, there should be an expression only containing $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thank you very much!